# SQL INSERT statement being performed when it shoudn't

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql

So my android application sends JSON data to the server, and the PHP script takes it, first checks if there are existing records of that user, and if not, adds them to the database. For some reason here, it's not working. The INSERT statement is always being performed. When I'm checking the count on a different PHP page, I'm getting the right count (using the same exact query).

But something is going on here. A new row is always being added, and I don't know why. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

require_once('connection.php');

$data = json_decode($_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'], true);

$name = $data['name'];
$profilePicture = $data['profilePicture'];
$googleId = $data['googleId'];

//First see if the user is already in the database
//$find_existing_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE googleId = '".$googleId."'";
$find_existing_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = $name";
$find_query_result = mysql_query($find_existing_query);
$find_query_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_query_result);
$count = $find_query_rows['COUNT(*)'];

//Add user if there are no rows returned
if($count == 0)
{
    $add_user_query = "INSERT INTO users (name, profilePicture, googleId) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$profilePicture."', '".$googleId."')";
    mysql_query($add_user_query);
}

$qry = "SELECT * FROM users";

$result = mysql_query($qry);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: You should be using the `mysqli_` extension since `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Additionally, you should use prepared statements or at least use `mysqli->real_escape_string($someVal)` for security reasons. You can also alias the column like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ...` so you access by `$rows['count']`.

Comment: And use a strict equals. I.e. `$count === 0` checks if `$count` is the number zero only. `$count ==0` checks if `$count` is zero, FALSE, NULL, an empty string, or any other falsey value, due to type juggling which is applied with the `==` but not with `===`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query fails due to a syntax error which makes `mysql_fetch_assoc()` return false which when type juggled equals zero.

You forgot to put quotes around the string value in your query.

```
$find_existing_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = $name";
```

should be

```
$find_existing_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = '$name'";
```

Comment: Just too quick to beat! Solid answer :)

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize that. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You've forgot to append and put single quote in your query. I should be like this:

```
$find_existing_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = '".$name."'";
```